# Union of large sets

Tags: import

I am trying to take union of thousands of set containing thousands of elements. However mathematica closes itself when I copy/paste the sets in `Union[{}]`. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problems?

Comment: Buy more RAM :D If you can post a minimal non-working example that would be great !

Comment: As suggested, for any intense program always buy WAY too much ram. That will repay itself over and over. If you can post somewhere, in mathematica notation and which doesn't require registering, signing in, etc. just to get access each of your sets then someone might take a moment to find the union. Also, can you union just two sets? Just 3 sets? or does it fail on the very first union. This x = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {10^6}]; y = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {10^6}]; a = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {10^6}]; z = Union[x, y, a]; finishes in one second.

Comment: I would perform numerous separate `Union` operations, possibly writing intermediate sets to a file, and then performing Unions of Unions.

Comment: First of all my computer has 8 GB RAM :)  Actually, since mine has less, I borrow my friend's computer. Well, the sets are written in a text file. I have found them by using the program "magma". There are 9880 sets exactly. The largest of the sets has 2048 elements. Even though I try to copy and paste half of the sets (roughly) from the text file, mathematica still close itself.

Comment: `Union` sorts the results, so if you don't need the results sorted, try `DeleteDuplicates`. Also, it is likely an issue with displaying that much data, so I would load the data in from the file using `Import` or `ReadList`, etc, and not explicitly display the data by using the form `data = Import[...];`. The semi-colon at the end suppresses the output. (Actually, it forms a `CompoundExpression` with the second argument being `Null` which has no output, usually, but this amounts to the same thing as suppressing output.)

Comment: Why do you copy/paste?  That is a poor use of cached memory.  Always label your sets and operate accordingly.

Comment: This z = Union @@ Table[RandomChoice[Range [10^5], 2048], {9880}];
MaxMemoryUsed[] uses only 850 megabytes and 30 seconds to union 9880 lists of 2048 integers. Try that and report whether it works. But nobody can really test your problem until they see your data.

Answer (score 5):

Don't copy-n-paste - that's error prone, simply do it directly from the text files.

Here's an example:

```
SetDirectory["junk"];

(* create 10,000 files, each with 10,000 elements... *)
Monitor[Do[RandomInteger[1*^6, 10000] >> "set-" <> ToString[n] <> ".txt", {n, 10000}], n]

(* read the files, Union as we go, resulting in final result of `unions`... *)
unions = {}
Monitor[Do[unions = Union[unions, Get@set], {set, FileNames["*"]}], set]
```

This completed with no problems (as expected) on an old netbook with a gig of RAM...